# EasySMPP library for C# does not work without Console.Readline() call

Tags: c#, .net, smpp

I have strange problem with EasySMPP open source library for C#, while trying to send sms using SmppClient:

This always fails (Console writline shows "Error"):

```
SmsClient client = new SmsClient();
        client.Connect();
            if (client.SendSms("MyNumber", "XXXXXXXXX", "Hi"))
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
        client.Disconnect();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

But when i just add this stupid Console.Readline call its works fine:

```
SmsClient client = new SmsClient();
**string stupidstring = Console.Readline();** //Thats it
        client.Connect();
            if (client.SendSms("MyNumber", "XXXXXXXXX", "Hi"))
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
        client.Disconnect();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

If i don't add Console.Readline() call it's not working. Could you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: I solved my problem used instead jamaasmpp which works fine -> http://jamaasmpp.codeplex.com/ , but the question is still actual.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a very old question. I was also looking but couldnt find the answer until i found out what the problem is.

EasySMPP library is using asynchronous calls to connect to the SMSC which is why when you run the readline() command line you are requested to put your text as readline and while there is a delay in your typing the SMSC has already binded by then. So it works with the stupid Console.Readline()

When you run without the readline() the code executes super fast and by that time the your application has not binded to the SMSC and it fails.

```
SmsClient client = new SmsClient();
client.Connect();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
if (client.SendSms("MyNumber", "XXXXXXXXX", "Hi"))
    Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
client.Disconnect();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding it by  `Try` and `catch` , make the `if` in `try` and `return` error at `catch exception.Message` .

Comment: Hi Amador. The client.SendSms method of SmsClient class did not throw any exception , it just return true or false.